# Десериализация объекта JSON на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, десериализация

Требуется получить список объектов класса Man

```
public class Man
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Secondname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Отправляю запрос на сервер

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "count": count
    },
    dataType: "json"
})
```

В методе контроллера формирую массив из объектов и отправляю клиенту

```
for (int i = 0; i < dif; i++)
{
    mans[i] = await manContext.Mans.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == mansCount - dif + i);
}
return Json(mans);
```

Каким способом можно получить значение полей объекта Man (имя, возраст и прочее)  из JSON при помощи JS?

Comment: Предоставьте пример сформированного Json сервером

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Пример запроса:**

```js
$.ajax({
type: "POST", 
url: url,
data: { count: 'count' },
dataType:'json',
success: function(data){
alert ( data.Firstname),
alert ( data.Age)
}
});
```

> **AJAX POST Обработка события кнопки формы**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery AJAX POST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="response">
    <pre></pre>
</div>

<form id="my-form">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        function processForm( e ){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://ip-api.com/json/',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    $('#response pre').html( data );
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#my-form').submit( processForm );
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Сериализация JSON C#**

```csharp
[DataContract]
class Man
{
     [DataMember]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string Firstname { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public string Secondname { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public Man() { }
     public Man(int Id, string Firstname, int Age)
     {
         this.Id = Id;
         this.Firstname = Firstname;
         this.Age = Age;
     }
}
```

> **Десериализация Json C#**

```csharp
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Man));

Man newitems = (Man)jsonFormatter.ReadObject(File.OpenRead("Man.json"));
```

> **Json JavaScript**

```html
<script>
 var user = '{ "Id": 1, "Firstname": "Вася", "Secondname": "Васильев", "Age": 28 }';
 user = JSON.parse(user);
 alert( user.Age );
</script>
```

Comment: Требуется проводить десериализацию у клиента на Javascript при получении ответа от сервера

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH добавил в ответ `JavaScript`

Comment: Здесь вы сами создаете юзера, а мне нужно доставать его из массива, который приходит от сервера в json

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH ответ на ваш вопрос: первый пример кода, далее разбор с примерами использования.

Comment: alert ( data.Firstname) выводит undefined, если выводить просто data, то пишет [object Object]

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH верно, ведь вы передаёте массив объектов, а не объект, следовательно: `alert ( data[0].Firstname)`

Comment: Знаю, что массив: я достаю через цикл имя каждого объекта и оно выдаёт undefined

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH выполните метод `Json(mans)`, и прикрепите результат к сообщению, предполагаю что у вас массив-Aray вместо Json

Comment: [{"id":40,"firstname":"Вася ","secondname":"Пупкин    ","age":34}]
Вот что в ответ приходит, оказывается надо с маленькой буквы обращаться