# Как вывести данные из ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ckeditor

уже долго колупаюсь, излазил все что только можно. Но не получается
Имеется плагин ckeditor.
В нем статически выводится информация в виде select
Работает примерно это вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код этого участка:

```js
id : 'hero',
                                            type : 'select',
                                            label : 'Выбери имя.',
                                            items: [ [ 'Mamba', '1'],[ 'Lamba', '2'] ],
                                            'default': '',
                                            onChange: function( api ) {
                                                // this = CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.select
                                                alert( 'Current value: ' + this.getValue() );
                                            }
```

Здесь мы выводим имя в список и при выборе получаем его значение.
Походу вместо вот этого:

```js
function( api ) {
// this = CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.select
alert( 'Current value: ' + this.getValue() );
}
```

мне нужен ajax запрос.
Собственно, в items мне нужны значения из ajax.

```js
$.ajax({
                    url: '/heroes',
                    success: function(data) {
                        for (var key in data)
                        {
                            // data[key][1] data[key][0] - примерно такого вида.

                        }
```

файл: heroes.php:
не знаю куда выложить php код. Так что так..
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLwYjP

HeroesController.php:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjWGjV

Нужно чтобы подставлялось значение $array[$k][]=$heroes->name; так и html код так же который в $array[$k][] в data[key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyuVX.png) и data[key][0]
Надеюсь смог мысль донести, уже отчаялся...

Comment: Здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817879/Десериализация-объекта-json-на-javascript/817895#817895 я дал ответ о десериализации, с использованием Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

В запросе укажите

```
dataType: 'json'
```

В  heroes.php выводите массив, как

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится, сделал вот так:

```js
jQuery.extend({
    getValues: function(url) {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                    result = data;
                console.log(result)
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
var results = $.getValues('/heroes');

CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'hero',
    {
        icons: 'hero',
        requires : ['richcombo'], //, 'styles' ],
        init : function( editor )
        {
            editor.addCommand( 'abbrDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'abbrDialog' ) );
            editor.ui.addButton( 'Hero',
                {
                    label: 'Выбрать героя',
                    command: 'abbrDialog',

                } );

            CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'abbrDialog', function ( editor )
            {
           


                return {
                    title : 'Выбор героя',
                    minWidth : 400,
                    minHeight : 200,


                   

                    contents :
                        [
                            {
                                id : 'tab1',
                                label : 'Tenants',
                                elements :
                                    [
                                        {
                                            type : 'select',
                                            id : 'style',
                                            label : 'Style',
                                            setup : '',
                                            items : results,
                                            commit : function( data )
                                            {
                                                data.style = this.getValue();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    ]
                            }

                        ],

                    onOk : function()
                    {
                        var dialog = this;
                        var abbr = editor.document.createElement( 'span' );
                        abbr.setHtml( dialog.getValueOf( 'tab1', 'style' ) );

                        editor.insertElement( abbr );
                    }

                };
            } );
        }
    });
```