# Как распарсить рекурсивный JSON-документ с помощью JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, json, json.net

Имеется специфический JSON документ:

```
{
    "user":"human1",
    "subsystems":[1,2,3],
    "query":{"AND":[
                        {"eq":["key1","val1"]},
                        {"eq":["key2","val2"]},
                        {"OR":[
                                {"eq":["subkey1","subval1"]},
                                {"eq":["subkey2","subval2"]}
                              ]
                        }
                    ]
    }
}
```

Необходимо трансформировать поле `query` в строку такого вида:

```
(key1 eq val1 and key2 eq val2 and (subkey1 eq subval1 OR subkey2 eq subval2))
```

Я использую Newtonsoft.Json, и не очень понимаю как написать такой **рекурсивный** метод.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817879/Десериализация-объекта-json-на-javascript/817895#817895

Comment: Не понятно по какому принципу строка выходная формируется, распишите подробнее

Comment: Это грубо говоря представление запроса (что-то типо обратной польской нотации), где ключ как бы операция которая применяется к объектам
`{AND -> [{item1}, {item2}]}`  ---трансформация-->  `item1 and item2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь есть определенная закономерность (я рассматриваю только объект `query` и надеюсь, что с остальной частью у вас проблем нет): значением является либо объект (с ровно одним свойством типа массива), либо константа. Поэтому напрашивается примерно такое решение:

```
static string GetFlatNotation(JToken jToken)
{
    if (jToken is JObject jObject) return GetFlatNotation(jObject);
    if (jToken is JValue jValue) return GetFlatNotation(jValue);
    throw new NotSupportedException($"{jToken.GetType()} not supported!");
}
```

Для `JValue` всё просто:

```
static string GetFlatNotation(JValue jValue)
    => jValue.Value.ToString();
```

Для `JObject` чуть больше кода, но не сильно сложнее:

```
static string GetFlatNotation(JObject jObject)
{
    var keyValuePair = ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>)jObject).Single();
    var key = keyValuePair.Key;
    var jArray = (JArray)keyValuePair.Value;
    return $"({string.Join($" {key} ", jArray.Select(jt => GetFlatNotation(jt)))})";
}
```

Поскольку мы не владеем информацией о приоритете операций, приходится каждый блок оборачивать в скобки.

Используем:

```
var json = @"...";
var o = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(GetFlatNotation(o["query"]));
```

Результат:

```
((key1 eq val1) AND (key2 eq val2) AND ((subkey1 eq subval1) OR (subkey2 eq subval2)))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я спросил аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном сегменте StackOverflow. Полученное решение, думаю Вам было бы тоже интересно посмотреть. [Решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509852/10126904) От [автора](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers)

Comment: Ага, мне кажется мое решение красивее